# Composition vs Inerhitance in java

Tags: java

#### description:

- I need write a new DTO(data transfer object) class `AppleRequest` use some of `PriceRequest` DTO class member.
- The database table field be like:

```
ID, supplier_id, supplier_name, size, color, price, etc
```

- I got a class `PriceRequest` which I can't change it, but my co-workers may change its member into `@NotBlank` in the future. So if I use `inherit` to achieve it, it may not work in the future.
- The `AppleRequest` class and `PriceRequest` class don't have the "is-a" relationship, it means not all `AppleRequest` is `PriceRequest`. In other words，they don‘t have any obvious father-son relationship, just share some of member.
- They are both DTO to a same database table.

#### code:

- PriceRequest:

```
@Data
public class PriceRequest {
    private int id;

    @NotBlank
    private String supplierId;
    //maybe @NotBlank in the future
    private String supplierName;
}
```

- AppleRequest:

```
@Data
public class AppleRequest extends PriceRequest {
    private String color;

    private String size;
}
```

- main

```
public class Sandbox {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        AppleRequest apple = new AppleRequest();
        apple.setId(1);
        apple.setColor("red");
        apple.setSupplierName("");
        System.out.println("id:"+apple.getId()+" SupplierName:"+apple.getSupplierName()+" Color:"+apple.getColor());
    }
}
```

#### what I have tried:

- just copy-paste all member I need in `PriceRequest` into `AppleRequest`. But it seems a little stupid.

```
@Data
public class AppleRequest {
    private int id;
    
    private String supplierName;

    private String color;

    private String size;
}
```

#### question:

- Should I use `composition` instead of `inherit`, or any better way to deal with this situation?
- How to avoid the change of `PriceRequest` make `AppleRequest` not working.

Comment: Composition would be `class Apple { private Father father; /* apple members: color, size */ }`. I find the example very hard to follow, how is a Father related to an Apple? Could you maybe pick more obvious class names, e.g. Car/Wheel, Father/Child, House/Room?

Comment: I use these name on purpose, because these two classes don't have any obvious father-son relationship in logic. @knittl

Comment: Yes but what kind of relationship do these classes have if it's not an is-a relationship?

Comment: Why do you have `public` member fields in these classes at all? And you didn't show a reason for inheritance so far - just because names of a field or method are the same, this doesn't mean you should inherit. In total the code in your question looks completely made up, and as you are writing yourself at the beginning, it might be a complete X-Y problem, not just by the title but also by the content.

Comment: To me, it seems like you are asking how they are supposed to be related but you are not telling us what these classes represent. And what's the problem with composition? Have you tried it and came across issues?

Comment: @cyberbrain got it I'll rewrite the whole problem.sry I made a typo, all members should be private.

Comment: @dan1st I have edited the question and add the real relationship to it.

Comment: @cyberbrain sry I cant just copy-paste my work code, so I made up it to make it reproducible.

Comment: looks better now. so you have two projections of one table, but the classes are not entities or similar, but really just used to transport data from one part of the application to another where the DB access is then performed?

Comment: @cyberbrain yes

Comment: So are the two request classes in any way related or not? Would a base class make sense, i.e. both requests have fields that always need to be identical? Or do they simply share fields that have the same name and (currently) the same type? In the latter case, these are independent classes and you should keep them independent (each class defining its own fields – it does not matter that the other class has fields of the same name)

Comment: You have to ask yourself: are the two classes logically distinct? Will they evolve independently? In that case, simply copy the members. Does a change in one class always require the other class to be updated as well? In that case, extract and reuse the commonalities

Comment: @knittl yes two classes are logically dinstinct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both classes are logically distinct, then bite the bullet and write two distinct classes. That way, they will remain logically distinct and changes in one class won't affect the other class. Copy-pasted code is only bad if it is logically equivalent. (Temporary) structural equivalence doesn't justify making the two classes dependent on one another.

If one class depends on the other (and it doesn't matter if the dependency is caused by inheritance or composition), then changes in one will always change the other. But if the changes shouldn't affect the other class, then you must touch both classes now.

You might want to read up on [cohesion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)): Change together, what belongs together (and your two classes don't belong together).

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments. Composition vs Inerhitance.

```
class Apple extends Father{};
```

Then the apple has all of the fields/methods of Father. If you want to use composition.

```
class Apple{
    Father father;
}
```

Now the Apple has all of the data of a Father, but it doesn't have to inherit.

Your example doesn't really show why the two classes are related, so it is hard to justify one or the other. Consider `setId`. In the inheritance case, you can just use the fathers method. In the composition, you might need to delegate.

```
public void setId(int id){
    father.setId(id);
}
```

Which is a bit cumbersome in this simple example probably just repeating the fields is a better way.

Comment: could you add a reproducible example code pls.

Comment: @leaf_yakitori I don't have spring setup, so I am not going to make DTO's with `@Data` tags that get turned into java code. I am not sure what you don't understand about my example. What I have written is reproducible.

Comment: @matt while this answers how to convert inheritance to composition, it does not address the underlying issue that the two classes are not related to each other. Quoting the OP from the comments: "yes two classes are logically dinstinct". So I'd say neither composition nor inheritance is the way to go here, but to keep the two classes completely separate.

Comment: @knittl I agree. I wanted to make it clear what inheritances vs composition most often indicates.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to consider: add a third, abstract class, say `Request` with the common fields (after all, both `PriceRequest` and `AppleRequest` are requests). For instance:

```
public abstract class Request {
    private int id;
    
    private String supplierName;
}

@Data
public class PriceRequest extends Request {
    @NotBlank
    private String supplierId;
}

@Data
public class AppleRequest extends Request {
    private String color;

    private String size;
}
```

Comment: sry I can't change the `PriceRequest` code in work, +1 for your effort.